# When is type applied to pointer arithmetic logic?

Tags: c, pointers, types, compilation, pointer-arithmetic

If I have some array of ints, let's just say:

```
int iarr[5] = {0, 7, 3, 12, 99};
```

Which is present at address `0xbfdf53a8`; and I want to print out the values of this with a loop, I can do something like this:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
   printf("value of iarr[%d] = %d\n", i, *(iarr+i));
```

This loop works because we're incrementing by one "int" each time (the address is bumped by 4 bytes each iteration on a typical 32-bit machine).

My question is, when is the type specified byte offset applied? Is that part of the compile process (meaning it's in the assembly somewhere), or is that done at the OS level?

I would assume how this is handled in a standardized manner, but I haven't been able to find that answer yet.

Comment: The compiler generates code to do it.  It knows what CPU/environment it's generating code for.

Comment: `*(iarr+i)` is exactly equivalent to `iarr[i]`. This is, of course, a C language feature and is not remotely related to anything that is done by the OS ... but it could be done by the CPU, on machines that have indexing instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the compilation process, the compiler generates code that takes the size of the operands into account.

Note that you can increment and do arithmetic with a pointer to a 5412-byte `struct` just as easily as a pointer to a 4-byte `int`. The compiler inspects the type of the pointer expression and generates the proper code.

The operating system is not involved at all in these low-level details, it's just code in the process from it's perspective.

Comment: Note, though, that on some machines there are `loadw address,index` instructions that automatically do the multiplication, but there are no instructions that automatically multiply by 5412. The OP may be incorrectly lumping CPU-level operations into "OS-level", and not realizing that the compiler has knowledge about the target machine that allows it to produce code highly specific to that machine.

Answer (score 1):

It's done at compile time, and will be in the assembly (and object code) generated.

The OS has no idea (and doesn't care) about the data types you're manipulating. It only gives you chunks of (virtual) raw memory to play with.

Only you and the compiler know the data types and their characteristics.